# Given a function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f'(x_0)$ is continuous in $x_0$, and $f'(x_0) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Given a function $$f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$$ such that **$f'(x_0)$ is continuous** in $x_0$, and $$f'(x_0) = 0$$.

Can one state that $x_0$ is either an extremum (local min/max), or an inflection point (i.e. where f changes concavity upward/downward or downward/upward).

If not, Is there a counter example?

I have this example but here $f'$ is not continuous at $0$:

$f(x) = x^2sin(\frac{1}{x})$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$

Thanks

Comment: Maybe $x^4\sin(1/x)$?

Comment: It all depends on the order of the first non null derivative. If there aren't any (because all derivative are null in $x_0$ or because all derivatives up to order $n$ are null and the derivatives of higher order do not exist), then nothing can be stated. In case the first non null derivative is of order $n$, then $x_0$ is a max/min **if and only if $n$ is even**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof of my statement in comment.

**Theorem. Let $f(x)$ a function defined on some neighborhood of $x_0$, differentiable in $x_0$ up to order $n$. Suppose that $f^{(k)}(x_0) = 0$ for $k=1,2,\dots,n-1$ and that $f^{(n)}(x_0) \neq 0$. Then $x_0$ is a local extremum if and only if $n$ is even.**

Note that we *do not* require continuity (not even the existence) of the $n$-th derivative in a *neighborhood* of $x_0$.

We use the notation $f^{(k)}(x)$ to refer to the $k$-th derivative of $f$ in $x$, and $f^{(0)}(x) = f(x)$.

WLOG, assume $x_0=0$ and $f(0) = 0$. Suppose also $f^{(n)}(0) >0$.

By definition we have
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f^{(n-1)}(x)}x = f^{(n)}(0)>0.$$
So there must be a neighborhood $\mathcal N$ of $0$ such that
$$\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x)}{x}>0\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
for all $x\in \mathcal N\setminus \{0\}$.
If $n=1$ we are done, since \eqref{eq1} guarantees that $0$ is not a local extremum.

If $n>1$, observe that \eqref{eq1} implies that
$$f^{(n-2)}(x)>0\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
for all $x\in \mathcal N\setminus\{0\}$. In fact, suppose by contradiction there is a $\overline x$ such that $f^{(n-2)}(\overline x)\leq 0$. Then, by the Mean Value Theorem we would have
$$\frac{f^{(n-2)}(\overline x)}{\overline x} = f^{(n-1)}(\eta)$$
for some $\eta$ in $\mathcal N$. If $\overline x < 0$, then $\overline x < \eta <0$, and $f^{(n-1)}(\eta) \geq 0$. If $\overline x>0$, then $0< \eta <\overline x$ and $f^{(n-1)}(\eta)\leq 0$. Both situations contradict \eqref{eq1}.

If $n=2$ we are again done since \eqref{eq2} implies $0$ is a local minimum. (This depends on the choice we have done to set $f^{(n)}(0)>0$.)

If $n>2$ we can repeat the previous steps to show that
$$\frac{f^{(n-2k-1)}(x)}{x}>0, \ \ \mbox{for}\ \ k=0,1,2,\dots,\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor-1$$
and that
$$f^{(n-2k)}(x)>0, \ \ \mbox{for}\ \ k=0,1,2,\dots ,\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor,$$
for all $x$ in $\mathcal N\setminus \{0\}$, which imply our thesis.

---

You have already been given counterexamples of your assertion in the answer and comments. Here are some other examples to further work on your problem, and some remarks.

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{ax^n}{n!} + x^{2n}\cos\left(\frac1{x}\right) & (x\neq 0)\\
0 & (x=0)
\end{cases}$$
is an example that satisfies the hypotheses, with $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for $k=1,2\dots,n-1$ and $f^{(n)} = a$.

One last non null derivative is required in the hypotheses, as pointed out in comment. Otherwise no conclusion can be drawn. Consider for example

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^{2(n-1)}\left[2 + \cos\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right] & (x\neq 0)\\
0 & (x=0)
\end{cases}
$$for all $n>1$ **has a local minimum** in $0$. The derivatives in $0$ are all null up to order $n-1$. The $n$-th derivative *does not exist* in $0$. As an exercise you can show that $f(x)$, despite the minimum in $0$ is not monotonically increasing (decreasing) in any right (left) neighborhood of $0$.

Similarly
$$f(x) =\begin{cases}
x^{2n-1}\left[2+\cos\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right] & (x\neq 0)\\
0 & (x=0)
\end{cases}$$
for all $n>1$ does not have a local extremum in $0$. The derivatives behave like those of the function in the previous example.

Finally, even when all derivatives in $0$ are null, nothing can be stated. Consider, e.g.

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
e^{-\frac1{x^2}} & (x\neq 0)\\
0 & (x=0)
\end{cases}$$
and
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x}{|x|}e^{-\frac1{x^2}} & (x\neq 0)\\
0 & (x=0).
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can actually consider.

\begin{equation}\displaystyle F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}{h(t)dt} \end{equation}

where \begin{equation}
h(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
t^{2} \cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right) & t \neq 0\phantom{.} \\
0 & t=0.
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

As $h$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ then because of the fundamental theorem of calculus $F(x)$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$.

\begin{equation} F`(x) = h(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
t^{2} \cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right) & t \neq 0\phantom{.} \\
0 & t=0.
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

And it is continuous at $x=0$ but $0$ is neither an extremum (local min/max) or an inflection point.

Comment: Pablo: I've made a few small changes to fix grammar and spelling, mostly on the sine function. If you think I've changed the content of your answer, please let me know.

Comment: thank you so much