# How do I analytically check if a point is a local extremum when $f''(x)=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f'(x_0)=0$ and $f''(x_0)=0$, how do I check whether or not it is a local extremum? The usual surefire method is to check the sign of $f'$ before and after $x_0$ , but I'm trying to prove a general result (that even multiplicities lead to stationary turning points) and making hand-wavy arguments about the sign change 'near' $x_0$ doesn't
seem rigorous enough. Is there any way I could analytically check using derivatives?

Comment: What's the result you're trying to prove? It feels like it can be proved without referencing the derivatives explicitly.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4355099/given-a-function-f-mathbb-r-rightarrow-mathbb-r-such-that-fx-0-is-cont/4355368#4355368

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos That roots of even multiplicities lead to turning points, while those of odd multiplicities (other than 1) lead to stationary points of inflexion

Comment: Do you mean roots of polynomials? Or of analytic functions? Or do you have a general definition that applies to every kind of function?

Comment: I was referring to polynomials specifically. I wasn't aware "multiplicity" was defined for other functions, so I didn't think it necessary to specify

Answer (score 1):

Assume $$f'(x_0)=f''(x_0)=\cdots=f^{(n-1)}(x_0)=0$$ and $f^{(n)}(x_0)=a\neq0$. Then very close to $x=x_0$, it is known that $ f(x)$ lies very close to $\frac a{n!}(x-x_0)^n$ (this is a simplified version of Taylor's theorem). So the first non-zero derivative tells you whether $f$ has a maximum ($n$ even and $a>0$) a minimum ($n$ even, $a<0$), or neither ($n$ odd).